# Uninstalling Google Earth. Something that I can't find anywhere in the web

Tags: google-earth

I usually don't ask for help unless I really can't find the answer myself. So, I'll explain where I got into.
I installed the Google Earth using this:

```
wget http://dl.google.com/earth/client/current/GoogleEarthLinux.bin && chmod +x GoogleEarthLinux.bin && ./GoogleEarthLinux.bin
```

I tried:
1) udo apt-get purge google-earth-stable

I can't find the exact package (dpkg --list 'google-earth*' | cat) because it writes that I don't have any Google Earth installed.
   sudo apt-get autoremove

All I get is:

```
zack@Zack-OS:~$ exec "$UNINSTALL" -L google-earth "/home/zack/google-earth/.manifest/google-earth.xml" "$1"
bash: exec: : not found
zack@Zack-OS:~$ sudo apt-get  --purge autoremove google earth
[sudo] password for zack: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package google
E: Unable to locate package earth
```

The problem is that I have the folder home/google-earh
Please, help me, guys)

I have Linux Ubuntu 14.04LTS, 64-bit

**Answer is found** thanks to @Rinzwind

cd ~/google-earth
chmod 750 uninstall
./uninstall

Plus to remove the download

cd ~/
rm GoogleEarthLinux.bin

Comment: Where exactly is Google Earth located on your system?

Comment: @dobey I try to find it but with zero result:         
zack@Zack-OS:~$ dpkg-query -l 'google*'
dpkg-query: no packages found matching google*
zack@Zack-OS:~$ dpkg-query -l 'earth*'      
dpkg-query: no packages found matching earth*                                                                                                                                         BUT! I can locate Google earth in /home/google-earth.

Comment: It should be quite clear for you that if you don't install things through dpkg/APT it won't keep track of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if you did not use "apt-get" to install forget about "apt-get" for removing software.
2. "home/google-earh"

   Please be precise. that part you typed there contains typos. I would assume it is installed in `/home/zack/google-earth`. If so you should check inside the `google-earth` directory. There is an "uninstall" in there.

   That would be

   ```
   cd ~/google-earth
   chmod 750 uninstall
   ./uninstall
   ```

   Plus to remove the download

   ```
   cd ~/
   rm GoogleEarthLinux.bin
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your reponce! What I have is this: in files I have Home folder and I can locate Google-earth folder there. Yes. There is uninstall, but what should I do with it? Can you help me, please?

Comment: `./uninstall` of course (just make sure it is executable.

Comment: And in addition, I have GoogleEarthLinux.bin in my home/zack/ folder

Comment: Okay.  Thank you! It seems there's no home/zack/google-earth anymore, though I still have GoogleEarthLinux.bin and desktop icon. Should I just delete it?

Comment: yes sir. That should be enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a newbie to Linux and sometimes it gets really frustrating. Though I enjoy it with your help! I'm lucky that people are ready to help. Thank you again.

Comment: @user491656 Please consider placing a check mark under the answer that you found helpful in resolving your problem.  When others having a similar problem, seeing questions with resolutions helps them to find the useful answers quicker.

Comment: Already done. Thanks again. That was the first time I decided to ask for help and I am highly impressed with the community of Linux. Terrific!